# Got around 15 "serial" upvotes in 2 days

Tags: discussion

Is it normal or some user would be deliberately doing it? Haven't happened before. I think it might look suspicious to SE. And might create bad image for my account?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Sometimes this happens when a user is very happy with one of your answers and checks out your profile and finds other helpful answers (or just wants 'reward' you). I wouldn't worry about this too much... if the SE algorithm determines it as "serial upvoting" it will get automatically reversed within a couple days.

Comment: @Welz: This is already a few days old, so it got around the serial-voting detection. Anyway, I am investigating it, but it may take some time before I know what it was (which I then may or may not be allowed to reveal here). Either way, there is no indication that Vikas is to blame for this.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft I wouldn't worry about it as long as it is *not* a spam/bot voting :)

Comment: @Vikas: Well, that’s what I am about to find out.

Comment: Looking at the [highest monthly voters](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Voters&filter=month), looks like there's a user upvoting many posts, possibly [for badge hunting](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/badges/28/electorate?userid=173945)...

Comment: It could be true. I got four more yesterday @AndrewT.

Comment: @AndrewT.: Just a note to future visitors: Be aware that the voter round-up may have considerably changed in the course of resolving this issue. Thus, please think twice before condemning whoever is listed there now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem has been resolved. See [this post on Meta SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/379353/255554) for what little additional detail you can get. Thanks for bringing this to our attention.